# Environment Variable not expanding

Tags: windows, batch-file

Platform: Windows Vista Service Pack 2 (x86)

I was messing around with batch scripts and realized that they could act as the command prompt(yes I know batch scripts run threw the command prompt) I mean that a batch script could prompt the user for a command and then call the command.

```
SET command=
SET /P command=%cd%^>

ECHO(
%command%
ECHO(
```

The only problem is that when I type in for example cd %windir% I get an error message telling me that the system cannot find the path specified. So I typed echo %windir% and echo printed %windir% exactly it wasn't expanded at all. I am wondering if the problem is because I have the environment variable nested inside the %command% variable but from what I understand CMD.exe does support nested environment variables. I tried using Delayed Expansion but the variable still didn't expand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `call` or `cmd /c` to evaluate variables that way.

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET /P command=%cd%^>

call %command%
ECHO;
```

Comment: I added CALL to my script and now it works perfectly thank you very much.